# Error: Program type already present, when adding QR reader module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, zxing

I've added the following line to my build.gradle:
`implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'`

and then got this Error when trying to build the project:

```
Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver
```

Can anyone explain the meaning of that error

This is my entire current build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chaimovy.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {exclude group: 'android.support.v4.app', module: 'INotificationSideChannel'}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'org.web3j:core:3.3.1-android'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
}
```

And can anyone suggest a way of solving it with the new dependency added?

Answer (score 0):

That library has a transitive dependency on:

```
com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
```

Which is conflicting with the transitive dependency some of your other app dependencies have on:

```
com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0
```

If you don't want to to use the transitive dependency that comes with zxing-android-embedded you can exclude it:

```
implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

You could also explore a resolution strategy for the conflict:

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    }
}
```

You can see all your transitive dependencies with the following gradle command:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies
```